# want to add screenshots to my read me but it doesn't work

Tags: image, github, readme

I'm trying to add a screenshot of the image to my READ.me file, and I added those lines to the file but none of them worked... 
Can anyone point me out where to fix it?

```
![](https://ibb.co/TWRByDK)

![example slide](https://ibb.co/TWRByDK)
```

I saw other people asking the same question but still, I could not solve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the link is not an image link, it's an html link. Try this:

```
https://i.ibb.co/FHJbpks/Screen-Shot-2020-05-13-at-8-28-14.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the image syntax, but the URL you've provided links to an HTML page, which is not an image.  You need to use a URL that links to a JPEG, PNG, GIF, or other image file, not an HTML page.